# django query select_related span relation

Tags: django, join

Well, there is a complicated query.
Let's say we have 3 tables.

```
class Logs:
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    ...

class User:
    name = CharField()
    ...

class User_Info:
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    address = CharField()
    ...
```

What I want to do is to associate the table Logs and User_Info via User.
Basically, I want to do a join, to get a new table which will contains all the field from Logs, User and address from User_Info. I know select_related. But it can only combine Logs and User.

How do I get User_Info involved? I want to minimize the database calls. So ideal answer should be one database hit.

EDIT:
I appreciate the answering below. I just wanna give my final solution for this issue.

If you do have some complicate queries, simply use objects.raw(). It will solve most of your porblems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**models.py**

```
class User:
    name = CharField()

    def logs(self):
        return Logs.objects.filter(user=self)

    def info(self):
        return User_Info.objects.filter(user=self)
```

**views.py**

```
users = User.objects.filter()
```

**template**

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ name }}

    {% for log in user.logs %}
        //log fields
    {% endfor %}

    {% for info in user.info %}
        //info fields
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the number of database calls doesn't necessarily relate to the number of lines of code - many methods in the Queryset API are lazy.

It looks like you actually have a one to one relationship between `User` and `User_Info`.  In this case, you can use a `OneToOneField` instead of a `ForeignKey`.  Then you can access your info directly from the `User` model.  See
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I don't have the right to modify the model... So maybe I have to find something else. Right now, I can done my task with 2 database hits. I want to reduce that to 1 hit. So you are right, I am looking for one hit answer rather than one line answer.